# Export HTML Table & its style to PDF in ColdFusion

Tags: css, html-table, coldfusion, pdf-generation

I'm working on ColdFusion trying to export a HTML table to PDF document. This HTML table is deriving its style from an external CSS file. The issue is that when exporting, the table format is not exporting in the pdf document. I need to export the table as its rendered on the browser(along with its formatting).

Following is the code for the same.

**Content.cfm**

```
<cfsavecontent variable="pdfREPORT">
<table id="dep" class="main_table" cellpadding="0">
    <tr class="h1">

                    <th>cell1</th>
                    <th>cell2</th>
                    <th>cell3</th>
                    <th>cellN</th>
    </tr>
            .
    .
    .
            <cfoutput query="qry1">
                <tr>
                        <td>#qry1.col1#</td> 
                        <td>#qry1.col2#</td> 
                        <td>#qry1.col3#</td> 
                        <td>#qry1.colN#</td> 
                </tr>                  
    </cfoutput>     
</table>
</cfsavecontent>
```

**extract_to_pdf.cfm**

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline;filename=test.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf">
<cfdocument format="PDF" localurl="yes" marginTop=".25" marginLeft=".25" marginRight=".25" marginBottom=".25"
        pageType="custom" pageWidth="8.5" pageHeight="10.2" mimetype="text/html">
<html> 
    <head>      
        <style>
            <cfinclude template = "styles/tableStyle.css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <cfoutput>#Form.pdfREPORT#</cfoutput>
    </body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code.  We can't really help without seeing it.

Comment: Don't the CSS styles have to be inline? Have you tried that?

Comment: @AlEverett Document styles don't need to be inline `<td style = "...">` but they do work better if they are defined somewhere in the document.  Most of the time we use my solution below, it works well and you don't have to maintain multiple copies of the css.  I think I've seen a couple documents where the linked css file actually worked but mostly we just use `cfinclude` inside a `style` tag.

Comment: Thanks AL Everett. We are using an external style sheet out here. Inline might help but using the same may impose more load on the code maintenance.

Comment: Welcome to the world of PDF generation in ColdFusion. It's horrible with CSS. As people have mentioned, do as much inline CSS as possible using style attributes on the tags. I would also suspect that it works best with 'old skool' HTML too (HTML 4). Try a test case, as if you were developing HTML for an emailer. Old, horrid looking code from an era that will not be missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing the code you're working with would help us answer this question but, do you have your CSS link inside your `cfdocument` block?  If you do and it still isn't working, try:

```
<cfdocument ...>
    <html> 
        <head>      
            <style>
                <cfinclude template = "yourCSSfile.css">
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                ...
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: Thanks Travis for the suggestion. I've uploaded the code above. But this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried 

    @import url("styles/tableStyle.css");

But no luck yet.

Comment: <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true"> may be preventing the HTML in your document from rendering despite being in a cfdocument block. Remove that and see what happens.